# How fast and reliable the Apple and Android push service? Should I use my comet server?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, push-notification

I'm developing a web app to use in mobile/tablet. Should I use those service or make my own comet server? I want a quickly(<3 seconds) and reliable (100%) solution.

Comment: Would like to know that HOW your own comet server will be reliable (100%)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple doc for push notification it self say that:

```
Remember that delivery of notifications is “best effort” and is not guaranteed.
```

You can read it here:
[About Local Notifications and Push Notifications: The Notification Payload](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1)